# Get All Table Row Values through Session Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, checkbox

I have an HTML table with one column having checkboxes. If you check a checkbox then press the "Checkout" button, it will take the specified rows and display them in the body of an email.

The top 100 rows are displayed on page load. I also have a search functionality where the user can search for specific rows. The user can maneuver throughout different searches and still keep all of the checkboxes checked with session storage. However, when a user hits "Checkout," the body of the email only displays the table rows that are checked and currently visible on the page.

So, if a user searches for a table row and checks it, but then navigates back to the original top 100 rows, that checked row would not display on the email because it is not displayed on the page at that current moment.

How can I fix this and show ALL rows that have been checked, whether they are visible on the page or not?

I have been told that I am storing the checkboxes in a session but then going back to the UI to read the list of selected items. However, I am unsure how exactly to fix this and would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

JavaScript that includes code to keep all checkboxes checked throughout session:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        //console.log('element id: ',$el.prop('id'),' sessionStorage[id]: ',sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')]);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
        if ($el.prop('checked')) {          
            //show the quantity cell in the column under header with class num
            $el.closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
            var quantity = sessionStorage['value_'+$el.prop('id')];
            if (quantity) {
                $el.closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner( "value", quantity );
            }
        }
    });

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});
```

JavaScript that sends information to email body:

```
function sendMail() {
    var dataItems = [
        { 'clss':'.loc',         'prop':'loc' },
        { 'clss':'.rp-code',     'prop':'rpCode' },
        { 'clss':'.sku',         'prop':'sku' },
        { 'clss':'.special-id',  'prop':'specialId' },
        { 'clss':'.description', 'prop':'description' },
        { 'clss':'.quantity',    'prop':'quantity' },
        { 'clss':'.unit',        'prop':'unit' }
    ];
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=";
    link += $('#merchTable tr input[name="check"]:checked').closest('tr').get().map(function(tr) {
            var str = dataItems.map(function(item) {
                return encodeURIComponent($(tr).find(item.clss).data(item.prop)) + '\xa0\xa0';
            }).join('');
            str += encodeURIComponent($(tr).find('.spinner').spinner('value')) + '%0D%0A';
            return str;
        }).join('') + '%0D%0A';
    console.log(link);
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

HTML Table:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Checkout</button>
</section>

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Description']) ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input disabled="true" type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

Function that display the `Quantity #` column when a row is checked:

```
$(function () {
    $(".check").change(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
        setupSpinner(this);
        console.log('input - checked: ',$('input.check').is(':checked'));
        //var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');

        if($('input.check').is(':checked'))
            $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(true);
        else
            $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(false);

    });
});
```

Function for the spinner:

```
function setupSpinner(checkbox) {
     var quantity = $(checkbox).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
    console.log('quantity: ',quantity);
    $(checkbox).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {          
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 1 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
          return false;
        }
          //store value
        var test = ui.value;
        sessionStorage.setItem('value_'+$(checkbox).prop('id'), JSON.stringify(test));
        var testtrue = sessionStorage.getItem('value_'+$(checkbox).prop('id'));
          console.log('testtrue: ', JSON.parse(testtrue));
      }
    });        
}
```

Function that gets values from each cell in checked table row:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#merchTable .check", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.check').length === 0;
  });
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('td').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('td');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'td') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "loc ui-widget-content":
              dict["Loc"] = value;
          break;
        case "rp-code ui-widget-content":
              dict["Rp-Code"] = value;
          break;
        case "sku ui-widget-content":
              dict["SKU"] = value;
          break;
        case "special-id ui-widget-content":
              dict["Special-ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "description ui-widget-content":
              dict["Description"] = value;
          break;
        case "quantity ui-widget-content":
              dict["Quantity"] = value;
          break;
        case "unit ui-widget-content":
              dict["Unit"] = value;
          break;
        case "quantity_num ui-widget-content":
              dict["spinner"] = value;
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: In your email body JS function, all you are doing is looping through the merchTable rows to find the currently checked checkboxes. Instead of looping through the actual merchTable, you'll want to loop through whatever you are storing in sessionStorage. If your first code example is all you are storing in session storage, you will need to rework that to include the data you need for constructing the body.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the problem but am not sure how to rework it.  I actually tried to rework it before and could not come up with anything. The first section of code is basically all that is kept in session storage. I use session storage in another section of code but its another function and works properly so I'm thinking thats the only session storage code that would need reworked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this and earlier questions, I understand that you need something that :

- stores the state of checked rows in `window.sessionStorage`.
- restores the state of checked rows after pagination/search.
- allows the composition of an email body, reflecting all checked rows whether they are currently displayed or not.

Without discipline the code could get really messy. I recommend a singleton object with a simple API, and ended up with the code below.

```
$(function($) {
    // **************************************************************
    // RowData acts as an interface beteween high level 
    // application code and sessionStorage.
    // *************************
    // RowData is phrased as a singleton object with private data,
    // and a bunch of functions, some of which are exposed as methods.
    // *************************
    // Inner member `rowData` is a javascript representation of all 
    // checked rows in the session.
    // A JSON-encoded version of `rowData` is stored in sessionStorage.
    // **************************************************************
    var RowData = (function(storage, storageKey) {
        var rowData = readFromSession();
        var dataItems = ['loc', 'rp-code', 'sku', 'special-id', 'description', 'quantity', 'unit'];
        var emailDelimiters = {
            'row': '%0D%0A',
            'dataItem': '\xa0\xa0'
        };

        function readFromSession() {
            return JSON.parse(storage.getItem(storageKey) || '{}');
        }
        function writeToSession() {
            storage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(rowData));
        }
        function writeRow(tr) {
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id');
            if($tr.find('.check').is(':checked')) {
                rowData[id] = {};
                for(var i=0; i<dataItems.length; i++) {
                    rowData[id][dataItems[i]] = $tr.find('.' + dataItems[i]).text();
                }
                // rowData[id].quantity_num = $tr.find('.spinner').spinner('value'); // if using spinner widget
                rowData[id].quantity_num = $tr.find('.spinner').val(); // if using HTML5 <input type="number">
            } else {
                delete rowData[id];
            }
            writeToSession();
        }
        function readRow(tr) {
            // restore tr's checkbox and spinner value from stored data
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id'),
                row = rowData[id];
            if(row) {
                $tr.find('.check').prop('checked', true).end()
                     // .find('.spinner').spinner('value', row.quantity_num); // if using spinner widget
                     .find('.spinner').val(row.quantity_num); // if using HTML5 <input type="number">
            }
        }
        function toEmailString() {
            return $.map(rowData, function(row, id) {
                return $.map(row, window.encodeURIComponent).join(emailDelimiters.dataItem);
            }).join(emailDelimiters.row);
        }
        // selectively expose functions as methods of RowData
        return {
            'writeRow': writeRow,
            'readRow': readRow, 
            'toEmailString': toEmailString
        };
    })(window.sessionStorage, 'checkedRowData');

    // **********************************************************************************************
    // With RowData in place to do the hard stuff, the high level application code is really simple
    // **********************************************************************************************
    $('#merchTable').on('change', '.check', function() { // on changing a table row ...
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0)); // ... set the corresponding row object in RowData and sessionStorage
    }).on('blur', '.spinner', function() { // on leaving a spinner widget
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0));
    });
    $('#checkout').on('click', function() { // on clicking the [Checkout] button
        var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=" + RowData.toEmailString();
        console.log(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    });

    // Call this function on completion of every pagination/search
    function restoreVisibleRows() {
        $('#merchTable tbody tr').get().forEach(RowData.readRow);
    }

    // ...
    // here, set up table pagination/search, and spinners.
    // ...


    restoreVisibleRows();
});
```

*minimally tested*

Note, everything above relies on table rows being served as follows :

```
<tr id="<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>">
    <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" /></td>
    <td class="loc ui-widget-content"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
    <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
    <td class="sku ui-widget-content"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
    <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
    <td class="description ui-widget-content"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
    <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" align="center" ><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
    <td class="unit ui-widget-content" ><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
    <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input disabled="true" type="number" min="1" max="<?php echo $row['Quantity'];?>" step="1" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" /></td>
</tr>
```

Here, I :

- added `id="<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"` to the `<tr>` tag - the `RowData` interface won't work without it.
- removed `data-***` and `id` attributes from the `<td>` tags - they appear not to be necessary but can be reintroduced if needed for other purposes.

Comment: In the `function writeRow()` the console is saying that `item` is not defined

Comment: Okay, heres whats happening...It looks like it is holding the checked value through searches which is good, but if i navigate away and then come back or refresh, the box doesnt show as checked even though it will display in the email

Comment: Yes it is the same in all browsers

Comment: I expect you just need to run `restoreVisibleRows()` on page load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147289/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-rataiczak24).

Comment: Hey, @Roamer-1888 I was needing to add something to this. I needed to paste a dropdown selection into the email body as well. Any ideas? I'd imagine it's somewhat simple, but can't seem to figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190241/displaying-html-dropdown-selection-in-email-on-button-press