# Displaying HTML Dropdown Selection in Email on Button Press

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onclick, html-select

I have a table where you can select certain rows by checking a checkbox and, on a button click, it will bring up an email client and paste those selections into the email body. This works just fine.

What I am struggling with is that I need to get it to also paste in the selection from the dropdown list but am having trouble integrating that functionality into my code. How could I do this?

HTML select:

```
<select id="pos-drop" onChange="updateinput();">
    <option selected disabled>POS - City</option>
        <?php foreach($pos->fetchAll() as $city) { ?>
        <option class="pos-city" value="<?php echo $city['POS'];?>"><?php echo $city['POS'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

JavaScript...the pos_city_selected variable holds the current dropdown list selection:

```
var input_num;

var pos_city_selected;
var pos_city_selected1;

function updateinput() {
var pos_city = document.getElementById("pos-drop");
pos_city_selected = pos_city.options[pos_city.selectedIndex];
if (pos_city_selected) {
    pos_city_selected1 = true;
    }
console.log(pos_city_selected);
console.log(pos_city_selected1);
}

$(function($) {
    var RowData = (function(storage, storageKey) {
        var rowData = readFromSession();
        var dataItems = ['loc', 'rp-code', 'sku', 'special-id', 'description', 'quantity', 'unit'];
        var emailDelimiters = {
            'row': '%0D%0A',
            'dataItem': '\xa0\xa0'
        };
        function readFromSession() {
            return JSON.parse(storage.getItem(storageKey) || '{}');
        }
        function writeToSession() {
            storage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(rowData));
        }
        function writeRow(tr) {
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id');
            if($tr.find('.check').is(':checked')) {
                rowData[id] = {};
                for(var i=0; i<dataItems.length; i++) {
                    rowData[id][dataItems[i]] = $tr.find('.' + dataItems[i]).text();
                }

                input_num = rowData[id].quantity_num = $tr.find('.spinner').val(); // if using HTML5 <input type="number">
            } else {
                delete rowData[id];
            }
            writeToSession();
        }
        function readRow(tr) {
            // restore tr's checkbox and spinner value from stored data
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id'),
                row = rowData[id];
            if(row) {
                $tr.find('.check').prop('checked', true).end()
                     // .find('.spinner').spinner('value', row.quantity_num); // if using spinner widget
                     .find('.spinner').val(row.quantity_num); // if using HTML5 <input type="number">
            }
        }
        function toEmailString() {
            return $.map(rowData, function(row, id) {
                return $.map(row, window.encodeURIComponent).join(emailDelimiters.dataItem);
            });
        }
        // selectively expose functions as methods of RowData
        return {
            'writeRow': writeRow,
            'readRow': readRow, 
            'toEmailString': toEmailString
        };
    })(window.sessionStorage, 'checkedRowData');

    $('#merchTable').on('change', '.check', function() { // on changing a table row ...
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0)); // ... set the corresponding row object in RowData and sessionStorage
    }).on('change', '.spinner', function() { // on leaving a spinner widget
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0));
    });
    $('#checkout').on('click', function() { // on clicking the [Checkout] button        

        console.log(input_num);
        if (input_num > quantity_num) {
            alert("The entered number cannot be greater than the quantity.");
        } else if (pos_city_selected1 != true) {
            alert("Please select a POS-City from the dropdown list.");
        } else {

        var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=" + RowData.toEmailString();
        console.log(link);
        window.location.href = link;
        }
    });

    // Call this function on completion of every pagination/search
    function restoreVisibleRows() {
        $('#merchTable tbody tr').get().forEach(RowData.readRow);
    }

    restoreVisibleRows();

});
```

Comment: IIRC, your table rows have a `quantity` field and a hidden `quantity-num` field. Are these the two fields that need to be compared to determine whether "the entered number cannot be greater than the quantity"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I did notice that part of my code is off, and yes they will need to be compared, but was going to fix it later as it is not giving me any errors currently and I have a pretty good idea of how to fix it...I just need to figure out how to get this dropdown selection posted onto my email whenever I make a selection and click the button

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Do you have an idea of how to get the dropdown selection into the email body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested approach :

- delete those three vars, `input_num` etc and the `function updateinput() {...}`, and any mention of them.
- add a public `RowData.validityCheck()` method, which throws if it encounters an error in the rowData, eg an entered quanity is greater than its corresponding quantity-available.
- employ a `try{} catch{}` structure in #checkout's click handler to orchestrate validity checking and act accordingly, as follows :

```
$('#checkout').on('click', function() { // on clicking the [Checkout] button
    try {
        // (1) perform validity check on the selected rows
        RowData.validityCheck(); // will throw if error is detected

        // (2) perform validity check on the #pos_drop selection
        var pos_city =  $("#pos-drop").val();
        if (!pos_city) {
            throw new Error('Please select a POS-City from the dropdown list.');
        }
        // (3) perform any further validity checks here (and throw accordingly)

        // Execution will only reach this point if no validity error is encountered.
        var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=Location: " + pos_city + '%0D%0A' + RowData.toEmailString(); // check that delimiter.
        console.log(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        $('#userMessage').text(e.message); // element #userMessage - eg a <span> - needs to exist somewhere on the page
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Appreciate your help very much!